# How to run multiple specs folders?

Tags: cypress

I have a multiple folder on cypress

```
cypress/e2e/1. Folder1
cypress/e2e/2. Folder2
cypress/e2e/3. Folder3
```

I know how to run it on a single folder using `cypress run --browser chrome --spec 'cypress/e2e/1. Folder1'`

But how can i run i it with multiple folders? Example: Run both **1. Folder1** and **2. Folder2** only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can send a comma-delineated list to send multiple spec files.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)

```bash
npx cypress run --browser chrome --spec "cypress/e2e/1. Folder1,cypress/e2e/2. Folder2"
```